# Do `SELECT` statements within a transaction return rows it has previously `INSERT`/`UPDATE`, when using the REPEATABLE READ isolation level of MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database, transactions

Do `SELECT` statements within a transaction return rows it has previously `INSERT`/`UPDATE`?

What confuses me is the description of `REPEATABLE READ` given below, where it says that the first `SELECT` statement establishes a snapshot that the other `SELECT` statements will use as well.

Should it be understood that `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations done in such transactions are also reflected on the (`REPEATABLE READ`) snapshot?

```
REPEATABLE READ:

This is the default isolation level for InnoDB. Consistent reads within the same transaction read the snapshot established by the first read.
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Comment: [yes, select](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=120e741992b0a3037fa91dcd2a42187c) returns the same data that is inserted in within a transaction, but not necessary those inserted from a different connection. This should be on dba.stackexchange.com/. Did you have a particular goal?

Comment: @danblack - thank you for your example on `SELECT`. However, where do you set the isolation level in your example? I will probably transfer the question to DBA SA.

Comment: [transaction_isolation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_transaction_isolation) session variable or [set transcation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-transaction.html)